# Filter an array of tags with props

Tags: javascript

Hei guys, im struggling with a problem here. I selected all elements from body tag into an array like so :

```
var DOMelementsOrder = []; 
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('body > div');

        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];
            DOMelementsOrder.push(element);
            console.log(DOMelementsOrder[i].offsetLeft);
        }
```

What i'm trying to reach is to sort the tags in array by theyr prop offset left.

The console in for loop return "40,200,85". What i try to achieve is to sort the tags in DOMelementsOrder in order of theyr offsetLeft.

Any help? Thanks in advance.

**ONLY WITH PURE JS**

**EDIT:**

What i have tryed:

```
function bubbleSort(a, b)
        {
            var swapped;
            do {
                swapped = false;
                for (var i=0; i < a.length-1; i++) {
                    if (a[i].b > a[i+1].b) {
                        var temp = a[i].b;
                        a[i].b = a[i+1].b;
                        a[i+1].b = temp;
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
            } while (swapped);
        }

        bubbleSort(DOMelementsOrder, DOMelementsOrder.offsetLeft);
        console.log(DOMelementsOrder);
```

Comment: what have you tried?... there are hundreds of array sorting posts on this site. WHat exactly are you trying to accomplish also?

Comment: i tryed to make another array with those values and sort em with bubble sort algorithm... doesnt help! Another try was to pass a parameter in bubble sort , the parameter shall be the prop offsetleft... nothing :(

Comment: Show what you tried. always get more help by displaying your efforts...even when they don't work...that's the whole idea of this site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and pass a compare function to compare the values of offsetLeft for each element.

```
// qSA doesn't return an array, so we have to convert it first
var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('body > div'));
// then we can sort
var orderedElements = elements.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.offsetLeft - b.offsetLeft;
});
```